# How to link to a file on a network share from SharePoint newsfeed?

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

Is it possible to post a clickable link to a file on a network share in SharePoint newsfeed?

These formats don't work:

```
x:\myfileshare\myfolder\myfile.xlsx

\\myfileshare\myfolder\myfile.xlsx

file://\\myfileshare\myfolder\myfile.xlsx
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One of the purposes of SharePoint is: not to have shared/mapped folders, just SharePoint. Upload file to a SharePoint document library or onedrive, share it and provide a link there.